# How to pull strings out of JSON object

Tags: php, json, decode

Here is the code

```
$jsonString = urldecode($json);
$jsonString = str_replace("\\", "", $jsonString);
$data = JSON_decode($jsonString);
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Cannot connect to database.');
print_r($data);
```

output:

```
  stdClass Object ( [myObject] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => abc [role] => ADMIN [username] => xyz ) ) )
```

my question how can i pull individual values and insert them into the database
 fullname, role and username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `json_decode` turns a JSON object into a PHP object, so you'll need to access it like:

```
$data->myObject[0]->fullname;
```

When storing your data in a mysql query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table SET fullname = '{$data->myObject[0]->fullname}'";
```

If you prefer to use an array instead of an object, you can use:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true); //notice the 2nd parameter
```

That way you can access your variables with an array like the two other posters described.

*EDIT*

You don't really need to use a for loop, you would just set:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$users = $data['myObject'];
```

Since you already have a perfectly valid array in $data['myObject'].

Comment: Is there a better way i can just pull all those values using a for loop and store them into an array

Comment: i did it this way but i see no new records in the table can you explain what am i doing wrong here? thanks in advance :)
$query = "INSERT into $tablename (USER,NETWORKNAME,ROLE) VALUES ('$dataArray[0]['fullname']','$dataArray[0]['username']','$dataArray[0]['role']')";

Comment: never mind i got it was missingthe quotes but thanks anyways for your help :)
$query = "INSERT into $tablename (USER,NETWORKNAME,ROLE) VALUES ('{$dataArray[0]['fullname']}','{$dataArray[0]['username']}','{$dataArray[0]['role']}')";

Answer (score 1):

to get fullname:

```
$fullname = $data['myObject'][0]['fullname'];
```

Same for role/ADMIN

Which you can add to your SQL string to insert into your database.

For an example of an insert into mysql see: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

if you do

```
$data = JSON_decode($jsonString, true); // just add true
```

then just use

```
$name = $data['myObject'][0]['name'];
```

and save it